# Equivalent of LISTAGG in LINQ doesn't work

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0, listagg

I have a SQL query

```
SELECT  
    M.EMPLOYEEID, LISTAGG(L.NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY L.NAME) AS Locations
FROM
    EMPLOYEEOFFICES M 
LEFT JOIN 
    OFFICELIST L ON M.OFFICELISTID = l.officelistid 
GROUP BY 
    M.EMPLOYEEID
```

The Linq equivalent I am trying to run:

```
var empOfficeLocations = (from om in _dbContext.EMPLOYEEOFFICES 
                          join ol in _dbContext.Officelists
                                  on om.Officelistid equals ol.Officelistid into grps
                          from grp in grps
                          group grp by om.Employeeid into g
                          select new
                                 {
                                     EmployeeId = g.Key,
                                     Locations = string.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.Name))
                                 }).ToList();
```

I have tried multiple versions of the above LINQ but haven't had any luck.

The error I get:

> Processing of the LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression:
> KeySelector: e.EMPLOYEEID,
> ElementSelector:ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
> by 'RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in Entity Framework. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.

The translation:

```
Compiling query expression:
      'DbSet<EMPLOYEEOFFICES>()
          .Join(
              inner: DbSet<Officelist>(),
              outerKeySelector: e => e.Officelistid,
              innerKeySelector: o => o.Officelistid,
              resultSelector: (e, o) => new {
                  e = e,
                  o = o
               })
          .GroupBy(
              keySelector: <>h__TransparentIdentifier0 => <>h__TransparentIdentifier0.e.Employeeid,
              elementSelector: <>h__TransparentIdentifier0 => <>h__TransparentIdentifier0.o.Name)
          .Select(g => new {
              EMPLOYEEID = g.Key,
              Locations = string.Join(
                  separator: ", ",
                  values: g)
           })
```

The result I want is simple:

| EmployeeId | Locations |
| --- | --- |
| emp1 | loc1,loc2 |
| emp2 | loc1,loc3,loc4 |

I have searched Stackoverflow, tried chat gpt; the in-memory version seems to work, but try the same code with a db Context and everything falls apart.

The database in use is an Oracle database, version 11g

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore v5.0.9
Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore v5.21.4

How can I get this working? I do not wish to do this in-memory.

Comment: i try to run your linq (replaced dbContext.EMPLOYEEOFFICES and Officelists as List of objects) - was lazy to create db schema - code works perfect. i can dump my example in answer

Comment: Yes if I run it with c# objects (lists) it works fine, but that's not what I want :(

Comment: Which LINQ provider for Oracle are you using? And are you using EF6 or EF Core 6?

Comment: Hi I am musing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore v5.0.9 & Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore v5.21.4. We cannot upgrade to the latest ones due to compatibility issues.

Comment: Hi @PowerMouse I think you left an answer below I saw while I was away from my pc, did you delete it? Or am I hallucinating?

Comment: I deleted, even it was a solution. Was start getting negative feedback

Comment: EMPLOYEEOFFICES
        .Join(
            Officelists,
            emp => emp.Officelistid,
            ol => ol.Officelistid,
            (ol, emp) => new { Officelists = ol, empOfficeLocations = emp }
        ).ToList()
        .GroupBy(g =>  g.Officelists.Employeeid)
        .Select(r => new {
            r.Key, 
            Locations = string.Join(", ", r.Select(m=> m.empOfficeLocations.Name).ToList())})
        .Dump();